# handle ctrl+c in client-server socket in c programing

Tags: c, sockets, signal-handling, ctrl

I wrote a telnet server in C programing language. Clients connect to the server using this command :

```
telnet *IP_Address*
```

I want when a client presses ctrl+c in its teminal, server closes the client connection but the server socket remains open. To to that put this command in first line of  main function :

```
signal(SIGINT, CtrlC_Handler);
```

and this is CtrlC_Handler function :

```
void CtrlC_Handler(int sig) {

     close(_c->_client_socket);
}
```

the problem is when client press ctrl-c in its terminal connection doesn't close and commandline terminal doesn't response to client :

[image]

But when the server socket is closed, client can types in terminal again. server and client are in different servers. can anybody help how can i caught ctrl+c signal in this case ?

Comment: Does your client code cope correctly with all the `EINVAL` errors that will result from closing the socket in the signal handler? What *is* your client code?

Comment: @user207421: The client is `telnet`. It is not "OP's client", it is a standard command-line tool.

Comment: @user207421 : I use telnet command-line tool. i did'n write client code myself

Comment: Pressing Ctrl-C on the client side does not send a signal to the server but to .. well .. the client.

Answer (score 4):

Your server handles the interrupt signal, which the process will receive when the terminal running the *server* gets a Ctrl-C. It has nothing to do with Ctrl-C being pressed in `telnet`.

`telnet` reacts to `Ctrl-C` by sending two control sequences:

- `FF F4` ([`IAC IP`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc854), Interrupt Process)
- `FF FD 06` ([`IAC DO TIMING-MARK`](https://tools.ietf.org/html/std31))

You can react to receiving these sequences (specifically, the first one in your case; reacting to the second one should be obligatory by the telnet protocol, but it's a moot point if you break the connection :P ).